# Javame sdk 8.3 doesn't work on Netbeans

Tags: java-me, netbeans-8, cldc

I've faced a problem with configuring Netbeans 8.1 to develop javame application with Javame SDK 8.3. When a javame project is created, Platform property remains grayed, compilation produced the message:

```
Platform home (platform.home property) is not set. Platform home (platform.home property) is not set. Value of this property should be <space> emulator home directory location.
```

When I try to fix project property on the platform tab, I see that:

```
No CLDC platform available
```

An old Javame SDK 3.4 works.

Any ideas could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion comes from the fact that JavaME is so much more than just MIDP/CLDC. It is used for so many other things, like e.g. Blu-ray players and other embedded devices.
MIDP and CLDC are merely JSR API's - which for some reason has been excluded from the SDK 8.x versions. This is why it can't find a CLDC platform, unless you install SDK 3.4
No other way around it than to use SDK 3.4

MIDP2.0 = JSR118

CLDC1.1 = JSR139

No where to be found in the list of SDK 8.x supported APIs: http://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.3/javame-apis.htm

Comment: MrLou, thanks for your reply, it makes the situation more clear. However, the page http://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.3/javame-apis.htm (reference you provided) points out that SDK 8.3 includes CLDC 8 which refers to JSR 360.

Comment: If SDK 8.3 in fact doesn't include CLDC, is there some tool which includes CLDC 8?
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Doesn't help you. JavaME enabled phones only supports CLDC1.1 (JSR139). Everything you make with CLDC8 (JSR360) will not run. Netbeans knows this, which is why it says it can't find any (valid) CLDC platform (for JavaME MIDlet development).

Comment: Thanks, Mr Lou. As I understand, my Samsung 5611 doesn't support any application, compiled with JavaME with CLDC higher than 1.1.
Let me ask one more question. When I compile my application, I'm now obtaining warnings:
warning: [options] source value 1.3 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.3 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release.
Previously I haven't seen it. I've found corresponding options javac.source and javac.target in the project. properties file, but I cannot fix it through Netbeans. Is it possible?

Comment: Those warnings doesn't mean anything (yet). Read more here: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/182

Comment: Thanks, the reference make situation clear. Nevertheless, can I set -source and -target options to higher value (e.g. 1.8, respecting to JDK)? Of course, it is possible to install earlier JDK, but it doesn't look good way....